# Exporting, Appending/Prepending data and text into files (Mathematica)

Tags: text, append, export, wolfram-mathematica, export-to-csv

I am exporting data from the table "mydata1" in a CSV format into "file1.dat". Below is the mathematica code:

```
mydata1=TableForm[Flatten[
Table[Table[Table[
                 {xcord, ycord, zcord}, {xcord, 0,50,10}],
                   {ycord,0,50,10}], {zcord, 50, 100, 10}], 2]];

Export["file1.dat",mydata1,"CSV"]
```

Now my "file1.dat" looks like this:

```
0,0,50
10,0,50
20,0,50
..
.. and so on
```

Now I have another set of data from the table "mydata2"(Code given below).I want to able to store the data from this table "mydata2" into same file "file1.dat".But before I do that I need to write a text in the file"file1.dat" for eg"Data below are from mydata2".

Note both data from both tables needed to be exported in CSV format.

```
mycounter=20
mydata2=TableForm[Flatten[
Table[Table[Table[
                 {++mycounter,xcord, ycord, zcord}, {xcord, 0,50,10}],
                   {ycord,0,50,10}], {zcord, 50, 100, 10}], 2]];
```

in the end my data file "file1.dat" should look like this

```
*Data from data from mydata1
0,0,50
10,0,50
20,0,50
... and so on
*Below data from mydata2
21,0,0,50
22,10,0,50
23,20,0,50
... and so on.
```

If you observe the final data file "file1.dat" should have data from table"mydata2" below the data from"mydata1" and in between there is some text written.

Note: I am willing to export the data with the extension TXT but in CSV format For example:

```
Export["file1.txt", mydata1, "CSV"]
```

I have used the "PutAppend" but it dosen't give me the desired results.Either I am not using it properly or perhaps it is not the keyword for my kind of problem.

I have lot of question regarding exporting but I wouldn't ask all of this now since I don't want to confuse you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
mydata1 = 
  Flatten[Table[Table[Table[
          {xcord, ycord, zcord}, 
          {xcord, 0, 20, 10}], {ycord, 0, 20, 10}], {zcord, 50, 50, 10}], 2];
mycounter = 20
mydata2 = 
  Flatten[Table[Table[Table[
          {++mycounter, xcord, ycord, zcord}, 
          {xcord, 0, 20, 10}], {ycord, 0, 20, 10}], {zcord, 50, 50, 10}], 2];

Export["c:\\test.txt", 
      Join[{"* data1 follows"}, mydata1, {"* data2 follows"}, mydata2], "CSV"]
```

The resulting file is:

```
* data1 follows
0,0,50
10,0,50
20,0,50
0,10,50
10,10,50
20,10,50
0,20,50
10,20,50
20,20,50
* data2 follows
21,0,0,50
22,10,0,50
23,20,0,50
24,0,10,50
25,10,10,50
26,20,10,50
27,0,20,50
28,10,20,50
29,20,20,50
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used your answer since it fitted my requirement

Answer (score 13):

Streams are useful for this purpose.  If your goal is to generate `mydata1` and `mydata2` at different times, then you could do the following.  First, let's create the file containing `mydata1`:

```
$stream = OpenWrite["file.dat", BinaryFormat -> True];
WriteString[$stream, "*Data from data from mydata1\n"]
Export[$stream, mydata1, "CSV"]
WriteString[$stream, "\n"]
Close[$stream]
```

We can verify the contents of the file using `Import`:

```
In[10]:= Import["file.dat", "Text"]

Out[10]= *Data from data from mydata1
         0,0,50
         10,0,50
         20,0,50
         ...
```

Now, let's append `mydata2` to the end of the file:

```
$stream = OpenAppend["file.dat", BinaryFormat -> True];
WriteString[$stream, "*Below data from mydata2\n"]
Export[$stream, mydata2, "CSV"]
WriteString[$stream, "\n"]
Close[$stream]
```

... and again, verify:

```
In[20]:= Import["file.dat", "Text"]

Out[20]= *Data from data from mydata1
         0,0,50
         10,0,50
         20,0,50
         ...
         *Below data from mydata2
         21,0,0,50
         22,10,0,50
         23,20,0,50
         ...
```

If desired, it is also possible to write `mydata1` and `mydata2` into the file at the same time:

```
$stream = OpenWrite["file.dat", BinaryFormat -> True];
WriteString[$stream, "*Data from data from mydata1\n"]
Export[$stream, mydata1, "CSV"]
WriteString[$stream, "\n*Below data from mydata2\n"]
Export[$stream, mydata2, "CSV"]
WriteString[$stream, "\n"]
Close[$stream]
```

Note that the `BinaryFormat -> True` option is used each time we open the stream.  This is to disable any automatic newline insertion by the stream write operations.  If this option is omitted, some unwelcome double-spacing occurs in the output file.